# GCP error while building a container image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-container-builder, google-artifact-registry

I have to test a functionality where I need to ping google.com from Google Cloud Run. For this, I created a simple python script to ping google.com.
I added Dockerfile and .dockerignore to the directory as mentioned in Google [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/python) . When I try to build a container image, I get the following error:

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/project_id/ping-google
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) The User is forbiden from accessing the bucket [project_id_cloudbuild]. Please check your organization's policy.
```

I am a storage admin and a Cloudbuild editor, what access I may be missing?

Comment: As a quick check, Run this command `gsutil ls` from where your running above build command to check if your able to access buckets in the cloud storage or not and check if Cloud build IAM user has storage permission or not.

Comment: Yes I can see all the buckets. In fact, the bucket I mentioned is non existent. I tried creating the bucket manually and then ran the create image command again, but I am getting the same error

Comment: Could you add more details to your question like cloudbuild.yaml.

Comment: I don't have any build file. I am just trying out the quickstart documentation, step by step : https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/python

Comment: I have followed the document which you shared, I was able to build and deploy it successfully. I would recommend you to use this command `gcloud builds submit --gcs-source-staging-dir="gs://<BUILD_BUCKET>/runstage" --gcs-log-dir="gs://<BUILD_BUCKET>/logs" --tag=gcr.io/project_id/ping-google  --project=<PROJECT> ` upload all the build files to the bucket which you created or i recommend you to create a new bucket and create a folder, Upload all the files in that respective bucket runstage folder and run the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some organization policy set because of which I was not able to perform this using gcloud. But I was able to create the container from cloud shell editor using steps mentioned [here](https://shell.cloud.google.com/?walkthrough_tutorial_id=cloud_run_cloud_code_create_service&show=ide&environment_deployment=ide)

This tutorial downloads the helo world code. I edited it to add my code of pinging google, and my job was done